# Failed loading /usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, ioncube

I just cloned a website from one server to another using cPanel import tool (probably this last part is not relevant)

The site is a Magento CE store.

The new server is a shared one, and only in this new Magento website I am having a 500 error:

```
tail /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log
Failed loading /usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so:  /usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

php -i|grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/lib/php.ini

cat /usr/local/lib/php.ini|grep IonCube
zend_extension="/usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so"

php -v
PHP 5.4.25 (cli) (built: Mar  4 2014 15:41:00)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies 
with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by ionCube Ltd.
```

So it looks to me very confusing... the 500 error is thrown because it is failing to load ioncube 5.3 even when the php.ini has the 5.4 version and the correspondent file exists, but even more confusing is that php -v shows version 4.4 ...

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With zend_extension="/usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so" you are telling PHP to install the Linux Loader for PHP 5.4. Your server is running PHP 5.4 so that matches.

The PHP output of "with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by ionCube Ltd." confirms that version 4.4.1 of the ionCube Loader is installed successfully.

The error you had indicates that a php.ini file is also requesting PHP to install the Loader for PHP 5.3, and this fails because the server is not running PHP 5.3.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nick, but looks like my php.ini is not loading ioncube 5.3 I tried the folloing: cat /usr/local/lib/php.ini|grep 5.3 with no results also: 
cat /usr/local/lib/php.ini|grep ioncube only shows: 
zend_extension="/usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so"
 Any help? thanks in advance...

Comment: I found this: 

find /usr -name ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so
/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/53/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so

Can be that cpanel is trying to load his own ioncube? if yes how do I avoid that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The system you migrated from uses a different version of PHP and you are using the wrong configuration file.

load up phpinfo and look for "Loaded Configuration File"

update your settings to use the config file mentioned by phpinfo.

I had a related issue with cron jobs for magento which gave me the same errors.
In my case PHP 5.6 > PHP 7

All the files were present, but what a mentioned above showed me the root of the error.

OLD COMMAND +

> /usr/local/bin/php -c /usr/local/lib/php.ini
>   /home/devlivingfresh/public_html/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran
>   jobs by schedule" >>
>   /home/devlivingfresh/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log

NEW COMMAND

> /usr/local/bin/php -c /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.ini
>   /home/devlivingfresh/public_html/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran
>   jobs by schedule" >>
>   /home/devlivingfresh/public_html/var/log/magento.cron.log